# "Cannot convert value of type '()' to UIImage": Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage

I am trying to load a UIImage from a URL and then pass that UIImage back through a closure.

This is the code to get the image:

```
func getImageFromData(_ imgURL:URL, completion: @escaping imageClosure) {

    print("Download Started")
    getDataFromUrl(url: imgURL) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }

        if let thisImage = UIImage(data: data) {
            completion(thisImage)
        }

    }

}

func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
        }.resume()
}
```

this is imageClosure

```
typealias imageClosure = (_ thisImage:UIImage) -> Void
```

and I am calling as such

```
let thisImage:UIImage = myAPIManager.getImageFromData(thisImageURL, completion: { (thisImage:UIImage) in

    })
```

and I get the error on the above line:

```
Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'UIImage'
```

Comment: Your definition of `getImageFromData` returns `Void` (a type whose only member is also called `Void`, a.k.a the empty tuple, `()`). It doesn't return an image.

Comment: What's the point of `getDataFromUrl`? It just wraps URLSession in a non-extensible way, that really doesn't buy you much. And the closure `{ data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
        }` could just be written as `completion`. `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completion).resume()`

Comment: Actually this was my problem: let thisImage:UIImage =...don't know why I put that there, end of a long day. But thanks for the other advice on the code. @Alexander - didn't see your first comment - make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of getImageFromData returns Void (a type whose only member is also called Void, a.k.a the empty tuple, ()). It doesn't return an image.

You need to set the image inside the callback closure, not by assigning the non-existent return value of the function.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the extra set of eyes is all that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

This funcction `getImageFromData` not return value

Edit this

```
let thisImage:UIImage = myAPIManager.getImageFromData(thisImageURL, completion: { (thisImage:UIImage) in

    })
```

To this

```
myAPIManager.getImageFromData(thisImageURL, completion: { (thisImage:UIImage) in

let myImage:UIImage = thisImage

    })
```